# Запомнить позицию последнего измененного символа Replace

Tags: c#

Есть задание, в котором нужно в строке заменить все повествовательные предложения на восклицательные, а все восклицательные на вопросительные. После этого выделить последнее отредактированное предложение (Цветом или символами с обеих сторон). Заменяю символы в строке с помощью функции Replace, но **нужно запомнить последний отредактированный символ, чтобы можно было выделить предложение**. Я находил в интернете Replace принимающий 3 аргумента:

```
Str.Replace(old string, new string, количество изменений)
```

Но видимо данную функцию убрали, т.к. у меня компилятор данное выражение не воспринимает. Так возможно ли запомнить позицию последнего измененного символа с помощью данной функции или лучше использовать цикл и идти по строке по символам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вызвать сначала `String.LastIndexOf` и передать значение, которое собираетесь менять.

Таким образом вы получите индекс первой буквы первого совпадения шаблона начиная справа.

После этого делаете стандартный Replace.

Все, у вас на руках index и можете делать с ним все, что захотите.